# java servlet login with role

Tags: java, servlets, roles

I'm starting with java, and I have difficulty to implement login. 
I would like my servlet redirects the user in different ways depending on the role (which is registered in the DB) 
I have tried so many different versions, I carry the last attempt. 
I do not understand why does not work (if I login as admin the servlet redirect  at the page for users)
if there are other errors (also logical) please tell me. I would like to improve. 
Thank you all for the answers.

My DAO:

```
public String esisteAccount (Account a) {
        Account acc = new Account();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '?' and password='?'";
        query=query.replaceFirst("[?]", (a.getUsername()));
        query=query.replaceFirst("[?]",(a.getPassword()));
        Vector<Object> v =db.executeSelect(query, "Account");
        acc = (Account)v.get(0);
        String ruolo;
        if (v.size()>0){
            ruolo=acc.getRuolo();
            }
        else { 
            ruolo="nonAutorizzato";
            }
        return ruolo;}
```

my dbManager

```
if ( type.equals("Account") )
                {
                    Account a;
                    a = new Account();
                    a.setUsername( rs.getString("username") );
                    a.setPassword( rs.getString("password") );
                    a.setRuolo( rs.getString("ruolo") );
                    v.add(a);
                }
```

and my servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        Account a = new Account();
        a.setUsername (username);
        a.setPassword (password);
        AccountDAO accountDAO =new AccountDAO();
        String esito= accountDAO.esisteAccount(a);
        if (esito=="nonAutorizzato"){       
            request.getRequestDispatcher("../errore.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else {
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            if (esito=="Admin"){
                session.setAttribute("autorizzatoAdmin","true");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("autorizzatoAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            else{
                session.setAttribute("autorizzato","true");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("indexPL.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
```

Comment: use .equals method instead of == in string comparision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is the prblem

```
if (esito=="Admin")
```

checking two string with arithmetic operator is not correct.
instead of that use like this.

```
if (esito.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin"))
```